# Value error: embedded null byte when using pelican content command to generate my site on Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pelican

I want to use Pelican to generate my blog site. I install python 3 and Pelican by pip on Windows 7 with the guidance of [docs quickstart](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/quickstart.html). And I created a directory under `D:/blog` to store my site files. Then create a file named `test.md` under `D:/blog/content` and test.md's content is the same as the Quickstart guidance. When going to step [Generate your site](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/quickstart.html#generate-your-site) , I get an error
in gitbash as follows:

[image]

So, why it happened and how to fix it? Thanks.

Updated, use `pelican content --debug` command to get traceback, and the key traceback is here:

[image]

Comment: Can you try a different markdown file, maybe an empty one?

Comment: @poke I create an empty markdown file and get an error: Index Error string index out of range. Not just markdown file has the value error, The rst file and html has the error too.

Comment: Hm, maybe it would be a good idea to bring this up on the GitHub page so the library authors can take a look at it.

Comment: @poke OK. I will consider about it.THX

Comment: Can you post the full traceback by running pelican with `--debug`?

Comment: @Avaris Question updated, add key traceback.

Comment: Your markdown file may be configured to use a specific encoding (e.g. UCS2), and pelican may be assuming a different encoding (e.g. ASCII).  That could make it think you have an embedded null byte... that may be crazy though.

Comment: Oh...It seems like a python bug about date format. See [https://bugs.python.org/issue25023]. It says the bug will fix with the Windows update.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue25023), this problem is due to the incorrect `locale` settings.

Execute the fllowing code,if a error occur,there exists a problem about `locale` settings.

```
import locale, time
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ko')
time.strftime('%a')
```

**Solution:**

The error file is `utils.py`under the path`..\Lib\site-packages\pelican\utils.py`.Add the following code in `strftime function` to solve the problem.

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en')
```

After adding (for example):

```
def strftime(date, date_format):
    '''
    Replacement for built-in strftime
    ...(Omit some words)
    replacing formatted output back.
    '''
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en')

    def strip_zeros(x):
        return x.lstrip('0') or '0'
    c89_directives = 'aAbBcdfHIjmMpSUwWxXyYzZ%'
```

you can also see the Chinese version in [this blog post](http://xingjian.me/how-to-fix-value-error-embedded-null-byte-error.html)

Comment: Could you add the information of the blog post to your answer? Both to prevent link rot and to help people who don't speak Chinese.